# JavaScript Raphael using delay

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I have this code, but the delay on the animations is is only from the start of the animation, and the generation of circles is not spread out as they all appear at once.

```
function generateCircles2(){
    if (totalDelay < 110){
       totalDelay += 1;
       var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
       var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
       var circle = paper.circle(-50,position,size);
       var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4000) + 2000;
       circle.attr("fill", "#000000");
       var cirAni = Raphael.animation({cy: position, cx: 850}, time, generateCircles3());
       circle.animate(cirAni.delay(100));

    }
}

function generateCircles3(){
    var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
    var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    var circle = paper.circle(-50,position,size);
    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4000) + 2000;
    circle.attr("fill", "#000000");
    var cirAni = Raphael.animation({cy: position, cx: 850}, time, generateCircles2());
    circle.animate(cirAni.delay(100));
}
```

How can I get the circles generated one every 100ms and not all at once? Thanks

Comment: If you can organize reproducible example in JSFiddle, I can take a look.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3yd8bfde/8/

Comment: Nothing happens when I run it. Please add HTML/CSS.

Comment: Sorry, complete beginner here and never used jsfiddle before and can't figure out how to run it

Comment: Can you add your HTML/CSS to the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with your fiddle. It was not working. But then I got it working.

I fiddled with it a bit. Here is what I got. I am not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for tho.

[Created this new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bocu/apf0enyy/)

Basically, what I did was to separate instantiation of each circle 100 ms apart.

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 800, 600);

function generateCircles2() {
  if (totalDelay < 110) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    totalDelay += 1;
    var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
    var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    var circle = paper.circle(-50, position, size);
    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4000) + 2000;
    circle.attr("fill", "#000000");
    var cirAni = Raphael.animation({
      cy: position,
      cx: 850
    }, time, generateCircles3());
    circle.animate(cirAni.delay(100));
    }, 100);

  }
}

function generateCircles3() {
setTimeout(function(){
  var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
  var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  var circle = paper.circle(-50, position, size);
  var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4000) + 2000;
  circle.attr("fill", "#000000");
  var cirAni = Raphael.animation({
    cy: position,
    cx: 850
  }, time, generateCircles2());
  circle.animate(cirAni.delay(100));
  },100);
}

var totalDelay = 0;
generateCircles2();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for